# SSH connection drops

Tags: linux, ssh

I have a bunch of tiny Linux (Debian Jessie and Armbian) machines at home (Raspberry Pi, Orange Pi Zero, etc.) all connected to the broadband router. With one exception (CHIP from Next Thing Co), they refuse SSH connection after a while. It's not just that the connection drops but it's impossible to log back once it happens and I need to restart them. Needless to say, I've tried adding ServerAliveInterval and ServerAliveCountMax to /etc/ssh/sshd_config but it makes no difference. I've also tried SSH from different machines. How can I make sure I can SSH into my Linux servers any time?

Comment: Why the markdown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `sshd` from `inetd`. inetd.conf:

> ssh   stream  tcp nowait  root    /usr/sbin/sshd -i